# LWC - How to add validation to LIghtning-input

Tags: javascript, lwc

IN HTML

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Lead">
       <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
       <lightning-input-field class="inputCmp" field-name="Phone"  
                       value={leadRecord.Phone} 
                       pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$" 
                       message-when-pattern-mismatch="Please enter a valid phone number" 
                       onchange={validate} 
                       maxlength="10"> 
       </lightning-input-field>
 </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

IN JS file

```
validate(event){
        var inputCmp = this.template.querySelector('.inputCmp');
        alert(inputCmp);
        var value = inputCmp.value;
        alert(value);
        if (value != null && value.toString().length > 10) {
            alert('Please enter 10 digit phone number');
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity('Please enter 10 digit phone number');
        }
        else {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity(''); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
         }
       inputCmp.reportValidity(); // Tells lightning-input to show the error right away without needing interaction
    
}
```

I am trying to validate the phone field to show error when someone enters more than 10digits and form can not be submitted. I tried to use

1. Maxlength - not working
2. setCustomValidity - not working
3. pattern attribute - not working

Any inputs please?